# How to use or replace 'WITH RECURSIVE' in a SQLite trigger to update a tree-structured table

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, tree-structure

In SQLite, I have a tree-structured table called `layer` with columns `(id, ..., parentId)`. And a normal table called `dir` with columns `(id, ..., modifiedTime)` .The situation is:

**Once some rows in `dir` are updated with new modifiedTime, all parents of them should also be updated**. Guarantee that the modifiedTime is non-decreasing.

Without a trigger, I could use this sql to do it(by using WITH RECURSIVE clause):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE P(id) AS (
     SELECT parentId FROM layer WHERE id="The Id of Modified Row"
     UNION ALL
     SELECT L.parentId FROM layer AS L, P WHERE L.id=P.id)
UPDATE dir SET modifiedT=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id IN P;
```

But the UPDATE statement makes an error when I put the sql into a trigger. After reading the [SQLite offical doc](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html), I got that `The WITH clause cannot be used within a CREATE TRIGGER.`

#### That's the issue

How can I make the trigger do what I want?

In another word, how to replace the 'WITH' clause within a trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [recursive trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_recursive_triggers) (available as SQLite 3.6.18), along the lines of this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_parent_modifiedT
AFTER UPDATE OF modifiedT ON layer
BEGIN
  UPDATE
    layer
  SET
    modifiedT = (SELECT modifiedT FROM NEW WHERE id = layer.id)
  WHERE
    id IN (SELECT parentId FROM NEW);
END;
```

This trigger reacts to changes of `modifiedT` only and replicates its value on the parent row. The correlated subquery syntax is necessary because `NEW` always can contain more than one record.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_self_modifiedT
AFTER UPDATE OF parentId, name, all, other, columns, except_modifiedT ON layer
BEGIN
  UPDATE
    layer
  SET
    modifiedT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE
    id IN (SELECT id FROM NEW);
END;
```

This trigger reacts to changes on any column *except* `modifiedT` and sets the current timestamp. In combination they should achieve the wanted effect.

You should create two more triggers that cover `INSERT` and `DELETE` and set the parent `modifiedT`, otherwise adding/removing children will not reflect on parents.

Note that recursive triggers must be enabled at the connection level:

```
PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;
```